# rosmake tf2 osx fails

Tags: ros-groovy, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I try to rosmake -a in osx Mountain Lion, it fails in tf2 package. I am following the installation tutorial ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source, with the exception that I am compiling rviz direclty from git devel version. I get the following output.

> mkdir -p bin cd build && cmake -Wdev
> -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/Users/mllofriu/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/ros/core/rosbuild/rostoolchain.cmake
> .. CMake Error at
> /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.10.1/share/cmake/Modules/Platform/Darwin.cmake:190
> (message):
> CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET is '10.6'
> but CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT:
>
> ""
>
> is not set to a MacOSX SDK with a
> recognized version.  Either set
> CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT to a valid SDK or
> set CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET to
> empty. Call Stack (most recent call
> first):
> /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.10.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeSystemSpecificInformation.cmake:36
> (include)
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! make: *** [all] Error 1

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52761/rosmake-tf2-osx-fails/) by [Martin Llofriu](https://answers.ros.org/users/3832/martin-llofriu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2013-01-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a duplicate of this question I think:

http://answers.ros.org/question/50561/cmake_osx_deployment_target-and-cmake_osx_sysroot/

---

Originally posted by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) with karma: 1626 on 2013-01-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0